# How to use euler's formula for edges and faces?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Let (G, φ) be a connected 4-regular plane simple graph in which every vertex lies on
>   two (opposite) faces of length 5 and on two (opposite) faces of length 3. Use Euler’s formula
>   to find the number of edges and the number of faces of (G, φ)

So euler's formula says that e - v + f = 2. And with the question it seems to give 4 faces (2 opposing pairs). How do I figure out the number of vertices to be able to find the number of edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the number of faces of size $k$ by $f_k$. Then we find the following equations to hold
$$\begin{align*}
 v-e+f &=2&(\text{Euler})\\
f_3+f_5&=f&(\text{Def})\\
4v&=2e\\
3f_3+5f_5&=2e\\
3f_3&=2v\\
5f_5&=2v
\end{align*}$$
Solving the corresponding matrix equation we obtain $v=30, e=60, f=32$.